# Why does $parent.$index equals $index?

Tags: angularjs

In AngularJS 1.6.3 it is basically possible to nest ng-repeat.

I have determined, that in two nested ng-repeat the $parent.$index equals $index.

The following code is given:

```
<div ng-repeat="category in :: $ctrl.categories">
  <span id="category-{{ $index }}">
    {{ :: category.name }}
  </span>

  <ul>
   <li ng-repeat="data in :: category.links"
       id="link-{{ $parent.$index }}-{{ $index }}">
     {{ :: data.name }}
   </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Expected** resulting ID's for LI:

```
<div>
  <span id="category-0">CatA</span>

  <ul>
    <li id="link-0-0">[..]</li>
    <li id="link-0-1">[..]</li>
    <li id="link-0-2">[..]</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div>
  <span id="category-1">CatB</span>

  <ul>
    <li id="link-1-0">[..]</li>
    <li id="link-1-1">[..]</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Actual** resulting ID's for LI:

```
<div>
  <span id="category-0">CatA</span>

  <ul>
    <li id="link-0-0">[..]</li>
    <li id="link-1-1">[..]</li>
    <li id="link-2-2">[..]</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div>
  <span id="category-1">CatB</span>

  <ul>
    <li id="link-0-0">[..]</li>
    <li id="link-1-1">[..]</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Can someone confirm this behaviour? Or did I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working as expected.

```js
angular.module('test', []).controller('Test', Test);

function Test($scope) {
  var $ctrl = this;
  
  $ctrl.categories = [
    {
      name: 'cat1', 
      links: [{name: 'l1'}, {name: 'l2'}, {name: 'l3'}]
    },
    {
      name: 'cat2',
      links: [{name: 'l4'}, {name: 'l5'}]
    }
  ]
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='test' ng-controller='Test as $ctrl'>
  <div ng-repeat="category in :: $ctrl.categories">
    <span id="category-{{ $index }}">
      {{ :: category.name }}
    </span>

    <ul>
     <li ng-repeat="data in :: category.links"
         id="link-{{ $parent.$index }}-{{ $index }}">
       {{ :: data.name }}
     </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

You probably have some scope generating elements surrounding your child layer e.g. `ng-if`, `ng-repeat`, `ng-switch`. In this case you'll need to add more layers of `$parent`

Comment: Brilliant! I actually have an ng-if on the LI. replacing $parent.$index by $parent.$parent.$index did the trick. 

I am sorry for pseudoing my code too much ;) Thanks anyway!

Comment: @SteffenKowalski If you had tried to create a fiddle, you would probably had figured it out by yourself ;D

Comment: We will never now ;)